# Unable to pip install -U sentence-transformers

Tags: transformer-model, sentence, bert-language-model

I am unable to do: pip install -U sentence-transformers. I get this message on Anaconda Prompt:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.0.1 (from sentence-transformers) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.0.1 (from sentence-transformers)
Can someone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to Conda Install pytorch and then installed Sentence Transformer by doing these steps:

1. conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
2. pip install -U sentence-transformers

This worked. 
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But any idea why `torch` under `sentence-transformers` had a dependency on cudatoolkit and pytorch?

Answer (score 4):

The other answers weren't working for me even though I saw them working for others on other message boards. This did work for me though.

1. pip install torch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
2. pip install -U sentence-transformers

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try pip3? That might be why it says that it can't find a version.

Comment: I have pip version pip 20.0.2. Are you saying there is a problem with the latest version?

Comment: instead of typing pip install  you could try pip3 install

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But that does not work either. I get this message: 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ok, Im sorry, :(

Comment: Thank you for your answers Chris, Sam. I apologize for not acknowledging your help sooner.